# Extjs Grid panel - Hide a column with hideable=false

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

i'm using Extjs 4.1 grid panel.

i'm looking for a way to hide a column from the grid.
i can use setHidden but then the user can "unhide" the column again from the menu in the column header.
it seems that the hideable propery just doesnt cut it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
Eventually i did this:
in the grid's "afterrender" event:

```
var header = pnl.down("headercontainer");
if(header != null && header["getMenu"] != null)
{
   var menu=header.getMenu();
   menu.on('beforeshow',function(sender,eOpts){

            var menu=sender;
            if(!menu.items.containsKey("columnItem"))
            {
                return;
            }

            var columnsSubMenuItem=menu.items.getByKey("columnItem");
            var columnsCheckboxes=columnsSubMenuItem.menu.items["items"];

            // More code here...
            // See the pseudo code
   });
}
```

now i just looped through the columns and if checkbox.text == column.get_Title() && column.get_Hideable() == true then checkbox.Show() else checkbox.Hide();

(sorry for the pseudo code, i work with a Sharpkit that is a C# to javascript convertor, so if i'd copy pasted the code it'd be harder to explain.

Note: you can do the same with the grid's enableColumnHide event.

Answer (score 1):

use following config to column

`hidden: true,
hideable: false`

'grid.headerCt.getGridColumns()'

use above method to get all grid column and use hide() and show() to show particular column

This will work on Ext js 4.1

Answer (score 0):

You can configure columns property in initComponent method and insert only necessary columns into this.columns array

Comment: i want to use all my columns in different situations.
therefore i need the ability to hide a column in certain condition and the user shouldnt have the option to "unhide" it again.

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure the grid for each scenario. [Link to api](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-reconfigure) hint

Comment: this is interesting.
can i apply a new set of configs to the grid with the method even AFTER the grid has been rendered ?

Comment: Yes you can. Read the docs for the reconfigure method. It accepts 2 params, a store and an array of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I use the setVisible(false | true) on the column.
[doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-setVisible)